# Пример react-redux-node js реального приложения?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Где можно скачать небольшое, но реальное рабочее и работающее react redux приложение, которое позволит понять основную философию? 
Теорию перечитал очень много, но хочется увидеть пример в реальном использовании с node js. Как в реальной рабочей ситуации. Например небольшой сайтик визитка или вывод таблицы.